# Bounce scrolling in iPad (react)

Tags: ios, reactjs, scroll, safari

I've tested so many things but nothing works yet. I have a page which its content is scrollable if needed.
It is working fine in windows Chrome and Firefox but in ios and safari it has a unwanted vertical bouncing scroll.

I've seen that people here mentioned that this : https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce has been the solution for them. but how can I use this in react?

Answer (score 1):

Hope everyone reading is okay,

I've an answer from the future.

Run `npm i inobounce`

Import it to your `index.js` or wherever your `ReactDOM.render(...)` is

```js
import inobounce from "inobounce"
```

Put

```js
inobounce.enable();
```

Somewhere, I put mine straight after the `ReactDOM.render(...)`

Don't forget to put `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` styling on the elements which do scroll, they should also have `height` or `max-height`, `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`.

This probably won't help OP since I am a year too late but hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for caring! I'll try that in future cases.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I tried putting inobounce.enable() before and after the ReactDOM.render().

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `react-bouncefix` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bouncefix?

It's straightforward to use (from docs):

```js
var Bouncefix = require('react-bouncefix');

var MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Bouncefix className="Bouncefix">
      Hello from MyComponent!
    </Bouncefix>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think this package is not supported any more. Its last publish is 5 years ago. I tried to use it but throws an error